# Hilariously LOW fps!

Tags: animation, physics, workflow, keyframes, cloth-simulation

I was working on a cloth simulation in Blender v.2.83.4 LTS. I made all the assets ready and also had modified them properly. Then, at the time I started the playback, I noticed a hilarious fps roaming around 1 and 2 frames/sec. I had never seen this low fps in Blender.

My Laptop specs:

MODEL- Dell Inspiron 15 3567
RAM- 4 GB total. 3.88 GB usable
GPU- 1 GB usable
Processor- Intel Core i3 7th Gen

Yes I know that the specs are not so high, but I had done even more complex simulations and animations with ease in atleast 20fps.

Someone please help me out. [image: FPS PROVIDED]

Comment: Did you bake the cloth simulation?

Comment: i also have similar specs with 8th gen i 5 , but it happens rarely when i have heavy stuff like " Colth Simulations'